# How to map an enum in a one-to-many relationship with NHibernate?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the two separate tables.

```
[users]   [ roles ] 
+-----+   +-------+
| id  |   |user_id|
+-----+   +-------+
          | value | <- [Represented by the enum]
          +-------+
```

And the models for them.

```
class User { int id; IList<Roles> Roles; }

enum Roles { Worker, Manager, Director }
```

As you see it is simple "one to many". User has many roles. How do I map those models in XML?

Comment: Bitmask operations might solve this problem. But in this case I need to change the existing API.

Answer (score 0):

how is your mapping?
did you try something like this:

```
 HasMany(x => x.Roles)
   .Cascade.All()
   .Table("UserRoles")
   .Element("RolesEnum");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but came across this as one of the first links when looking for the answer. It seems doing this for the User entity will work (with FluentNhibernate):

```
HasMany(x => x.Roles)
.Cascade.All()
.Table("roles")
.KeyColumn("user_id")
.Element("value", m => m.Type<EnumStringType<Roles>>());
```