# How to map an enum in a one-to-many relationship with fluent API in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums

My question is simple, and related to this other one ([How to map an enum in a one-to-many relationship with NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422806/how-to-map-an-enum-in-a-one-to-many-relationship-with-nhibernate)) although here I'm specifically asking about the fluent API for Entity Framework.

Let's say (the same example) I have these two entities in my model, one reference type (User) and another an enum (Roles).

```
class User { int id; IList<Roles> Roles; }

enum Roles { Worker, Manager, Director }
```

Or in this representation for clarity...

```
[users]   [ roles ] 
+-----+   +-------+
| id  |   |user_id|
+-----+   +-------+
          | value | <- [Represented by the enum]
          +-------+
```

Now I want to use fluent API to map this to my database in Entity Framework, but if I try...

```
 HasMany(x => x.Roles)
   .Cascade.All()
   .Table("UserRoles")
   .Element("RolesEnum");
```

... it will fail, as `HasMany()` is not reference type.

Is there a way of doing this in fluent API that does not involve changing my business model from an enum to a class?

Answer (score 1):

This does not directly answer your question but have you thought about making the Role enum into a flags enum and storing it inside the User table as an integer?

You could do something like this:

```
class User 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public UserRole Roles { get; set; } 
}

[Flags]
public enum UserRole
{
    Guest = 0,
    Worker = 1,
    Manager = 1 << 2,
    Director = 1 << 3,
}
```

Then to store multiple roles in the user table you could assign them like this:

```
_user.Roles = UserRole.Worker | UserRole.Manager
```

Comment: It's not acceptable, as this is not a fresh development. When I'm tied to the binaries of a business model like above I cannot change that, plus if the database where data has been stored has been there for years and contains the above relationship, it is not a good choice.

In the worst case, I will map it to a class, but honestly, it should be able to map to an entity, although I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do it. EF (up to 6.1) doesn't support mapping value types.

There are several alternatives to do it: complex types, using a column with the serialized list... But they are tricks, not direct EF support.

Comment: Hi @JotaBe, any of these work-arounds that does not require changing the model?

Comment: It depends on what you understand by changing the model. If you want to use the serialization trick, and adding a new property for the serialized list is changing the model, yes it changes. If you want to try something with a complex type, yes, the model changes. But, if it's a "business model" why do you want to treat it as a "data (EF) model" instead of doing some mapping to keep your "business model" and your "db model" independent? We, developers, should find solutions to **business** problems, and don't spend too much time solving technical problems when there are alternatives.

Comment: Hi again @JotaBe... I will answer to your previous comment although its focus on the question at hand is = 0.

I have an existing business model that now needs to be ported to an OData service in WebAPI. OData for ASP.Net has been made so that it directly eats anything from Entity Framework, but that is very tightly coupled, and we want to loose couple the business layer from the db as much as possible. That implies that business model and its mapping to the db must be as less aware as possible, but I still need to keep the wonderfulness of IQueryable expressions.

Comment: ¡Compañero!, I'm afraid that the only solution is to create the "dummy" classes with an FK Id, and a value. Since EF doesn't support it and you want to expose the model through OData I think that's the fastest solution (if your client is .NET or JS I think it's still quite easy to do the mapping to give it the desired shape). I suppose that you've been using NHibernate, so something like this would be ideal for you: https://github.com/pvginkel/NHibernate.OData but I don't know if the maturity level is enough for production, or if there is some alternative. Google "NHibernate OData" for more.

Comment: Please, make that Google query. I've browsed the results and there are interesting things. If you're lucky enough one of these things will fit your problem. For example, if you're using JS Breeze is a great JS OData client, and it has some kind of support for NH: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/nhibernate-support. It includes server and client side.

Comment: Hi @JotaBe. In my question I specifically stated that the difference of this question with this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422806/how-to-map-an-enum-in-a-one-to-many-relationship-with-nhibernate) is that I'm not using NHibernate. As I've read, apparently for NHibernate there is some way of mapping enums to database tables, but I did not go into detail, as I must do it (sadly or not) with EF. I ended up going for the "manual" enumerable implementation, which is a class with static preset fields, and with ID and Name properties. Not elegant, but works. Still looking for solutions.

Comment: Sorry, in this jungle of comments I forgot about the original question, and I thought that you was using NHibernate because this is one of the oustanding differences between EF an NHibernateEF doesn't support any of this things http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1411663 There are "hacks" that could work in the C# code side, but, as your model needs to be exposed by OData you'll have to put up with that problem. Perhaps you can combine your solution with mappers (AutoMapper, ValueInjecter) or extra [NotMapped] properties, and JS mappings.